# Can't upload certificate to AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate

I'm doing:

```
aws iam upload-server-certificate --server-certificate-name MysiteCertificate --certificate-body Downloads/mysite/mysite.crt --private-key mysite.pem --certificate-chain Downloads/mysite/COMODOSSLCA.crt
```

I'm getting an error though: `A client error (MalformedCertificate) occurred when calling the UploadServerCertificate operation: Unable to parse certificate. Please ensure the certificate is in PEM format.`

It is a valid `pem` file though =(

Comment: Test that the uploaded cert is correct (linebreaks?): `wget  Downloads/mysite/mysite.crt -O webcert.crt` and then `openssl x509 -in webcert.crt -text -noout`

Comment: Yup, looks good.

Comment: try adding `file://` before the file names

Comment: Make that an answer so I Can vote for it =)

Comment: sure, glad I could help!

Answer (score 53):

Add a `file://` before the file names.

Comment: This is what it was for me. What a terribly unhelpful error for the AWS CLI to throw!

Comment: Seriously the least helpful error message I've seen in a while.

Comment: Worked for me as well.

Answer (score 8):

I've seen this when the key wasn't in RSA format. If you check the header for your key and it is `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----` instead of `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` that's probably your problem. You can get the key into RSA with:

```
 openssl rsa -in my-private-key.pem > private-rsa-key.pem
```

Comment: this is the only place i could find this answer. thanks!

Comment: I have it beginning with `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`, and its been outputted as a `.pem` and for sure `RSA`, but it still returns the same error. I generated the key with `openssl genrsa -des3 -out server.pass.key 2048` and `openssl rsa -in server.pass.key -out server.key`